# Qt WebEngine on fail

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebengine

I can process on success loading page using signal loadFinished.
How to specify fail loading page and process actions on it? I need to refresh page on fail loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at syntax of this signal - [void QWebEnginePage::loadFinished(bool ok)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#loadFinished)

More precisely at it's description - "ok will indicate whether the load was successful or any error occurred."

So just connect this signal to slot that accepts `bool` as argument and reload page (do other stuff like check connection etc) when `ok` is `false`

Comment: Thank you very much.  I need that)